# F#-Monodevelop comment issue

Tags: f#, monodevelop, comments

Beginning to learn F#, I decided on using Monodevelop rather than VS. The strange thing is, some of the lines appear formatted as a comment. I would appreciate any help with solving this as it is quite annoying. THanx. For example:

[image]

Comment: A wild guess would be that this has to do with the `(*)` being parsed as opening/closing a comment by the syntax colorizer.

Comment: A quick guess for a workaround: use spaces like this: `( * )`

Comment: please report MonoDevelop bugs in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ (product: XamarinStudio)